# Delay a function execution in javascript using underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, underscore.js, q

Libraries used : `Q` and `underscore`.

This is the following scenario in my code.

```
pollEngine : _.throttle(function() {
   return that.fetchStatus()
         .then(function(data) {
             if(data) {
                 //keep polling until the data returned is false
                 return that.pollEngine();
             }
             else {
                 return;
             }
         });
}, 1000);

fetchStatus: function() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    $.ajax({
        //code
       success: function(data) {
           deferred.resolve('true' or 'false' depending on data);
       }
       error: function() {
           deferred.reject('error');
       }
    });
   return deferred.promise;
}
```

This code executes first time immediately and if the data returned is true, the subsequent ajax calls are made at 1 second intervals due to throttle.

I want to delay the ajax call even first time by a few milli seconds as the server data might not be ready. But whatever code I try using `delay`, `throttle` etc. the `fetchStatus` function and the subsequent ajax calls are performed immediately .

Comment: Have you tried passing `{leading: false}` to the throttle function?

Comment: yeah {leading: false} parameter after 1000 - still same issue

Comment: Your requirement looks like you need to wrap `pollEngine` inside a `_.delay` function with the desired milliseconds.

Comment: I tried replacing throttle with delay, but then it throws up a console error saying cannot read fetchStatus() of undefined

Comment: If that's the case you have an issue with scoping your functions. Also you should be handling the case of no data at the first attempt, on the client side rather than delaying the polling function.

Comment: It works fine for throttle. Can you please tell me if there is any difference in scoping when it comes to throttle and delay?  the `var that = this` is in the first line of pollRuleEngine function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96429/discussion-between-sandeep-s-and-user2133404).